# Adding a Paper Size with PHPWord

Tags: phpword

I use PHPWord extensively, but I can't figure out how to set up a "Tabloid" paper size *outside* the library. Hacking the library file is easy enough, you just add this:

`'Tabloid'   => array(11, 17, 'in'),`

To line 109 on this page:

https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord/blob/develop/src/PhpWord/Style/Paper.php

But I need to initiate Tabloid *outside* the library as it's too easy to overwrite when updating, moving or deploying code.

It's strange that PHPWord helpfully lists every paper size in the file above, but then only initiates 6 defaults. The docs are also very helpful, except "Paper" doesn't even register in the search.

Comment: Is that not what you need to to do? Add the line above and then be able to use "tabloid" instead of "A4" in the class constructor?

Comment: @Simson The problem is I can't just add that line to the library /vendor/ folder, otherwise it will be overwritten in a future update and I'll forget to add it back each time. Plus I would need to do it for all developers, and production and staging sites. I need a way to initiate the paper size outside the Paper.php class

Comment: if you create a pull request for upstream it would be in next release.

Answer (score 0):

By the look of the commits this was created by quoting the standard in the comment and the cherry-picking what seemed to be the reasonable formats to support.

My suggested way to solve this is to fork the project at github and submit a pull request to the project. This way the project maintainers will be aware of this issue and it could either be rejected (because of some unknown side effect) or merged in the baseline for future releases.

*The solution outlined in the questions seems cumbersome and even more hacky, the proper way of solving the problem is to solve it upstream*

Comment: Thanks, I've added an Issue to the Github repo. I guess I can do a pull request, kind of the same thing though. It makes zero sense to me that they wouldn't just initiate all paper sizes they've so carefully curated, the overhead seems to be almost nothing to store 50 to 100 tiny arrays.